# How to grant permissions for a user to view but not execute a SQL Server stored procedure?

Tags: ssms, azure-sql-database

I want to grant a user permissions to view a stored procedure, but not execute it. I tried this but the user says that they cannot see it in SSMS.

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON MyProc TO SomeUser
```

How can I grant permissions for a user to view but not execute a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

i suppose you have to deny select to him

```
DENY SELECT ON OBJECT::schema.MyProc TO SomeUser;  
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing a screen share with the user, it was evident that the code below indeed works to grant permissions for a user to view but not execute a stored procedure. It was a case of receiving inaccurate feedback from the user.

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON MyProc TO SomeUser
```